# Can not find module wrench?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Dos showing that can not find module wrench.When I am going to gulp
serve the project.
Error:Can not add module wrench

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.I just missed the directory of project.
      npm install
      bower install

done the job.

```
var wrench = require('wrench');
```

is needed in gulpfile.js file.